# qemu-x86_64-static Exec format error after chroot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu-architecture, qemu, chroot

I am on termux with root permission.
My phone has aarch64 cpu architecture.
I'm trying to chroot a ubuntu filesystem with amd64 architecture
i've seen and this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222981
here's my command

`sudo chroot ubuntu /bin/qemu-x86_64-static /bin/bash --login`

i logged in successfully but when i run command
`ls` or any

it's give an error like `Exec format error`
then i tried that command with qemu-x86_64-static like `qemu-x86_64-static /bin/ls` it's execute successfully
any idea for this???

i think i can add alias for all command for starts with qemu-x86_64-static but that's not good idea...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the kernel that when it sees an arm64 binary it should run it by launching QEMU. The mechanism for this is called "binfmt-misc", and to configure it you need to write data in the correct format to special files in the host system's `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` directory. Most Linux distros will do this for you automatically when you install their QEMU packages, but obviously Android won't do this for you.

First check that your phone's kernel has binfmt-misc support compiled in at all: there should be a file `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status` and if you `cat` its contents it should read `enabled`. If not, try `modprobe binfmt_misc`. If after that the `status` file is still not there then you won't be able to get this working unless you can somehow build a new kernel for your phone.

If the support is present in your phone's kernel, you can try the `qemu-binfmt-conf.sh` script that upstream QEMU ships as a mechanism for registering QEMU with the binfmt-misc machinery:
https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/scripts/qemu-binfmt-conf.sh
(This is just a script which writes the correct lines of data to `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`.)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!  Very helpful!

For my sake, as I am coming from a Debian system, the command `sudo apt install qemu-user`, which also installs the recommended `qemu-user-binfmt`, does the trick of registering all the relevant binary handlers for me.  (I also have `qemu-system-misc` package installed for /usr/bin/qemu-system-riscv64.)